# Android Jenkins ant build fails

Tags: android, ant, jenkins, lint

I'm doing transition of android project from `ant` to `gradle` build. After draft of new build process I've merged my branch to develop. But now our `Jenkins` old build is failing because:

```
'<Project>' is a Gradle project. To correctly analyze Gradle projects, you should run "gradlew :lint" instead.
```

Is it possible to fix `Jenkins` build until we completely switched to `gradle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what command you're running to produce this output but, according to the Android bug tracker, this is a Lint error category that you can ignore:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60416

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to comment question that I fixed it like this. But I afraid that with this flag I don't suppress other issues

Comment: @EugenMartynov How exactly did you fix it?

Comment: Take a look for lint.xml http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings